# Best way to evaluate performance for my case

Tags: predictive-modeling, accuracy

I have dataset that looks like this

```
F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 A1 A2 A3
1  0  0  0  4  3  X  X  X
0  3  9  0  0  0  X  A  X
0  0  0  0  1  0  X  X  X
0  0  3  2  0  0  X  X  X
0  5  0  0  0  1  X  X  X
0  0  7  0  1  3  X  X  X
0  0  0  1  1  0  X  X  B
1  3  0  2  0  1  X  X  X
7  0  0  2  1  3  X  X  X
4  0  0  0  5  0  B  A  X
0  0  7  2  1  3  X  X  X
```

where F1 to F6 are the features

and A1 to A3 are the prediction attributes.

as you can see most of the records are `X X X`

when I build my prediction algorithm and try to evaluate the performance I use **f1_score**

but due to most records have `X X X` values, I get high **f1_score**.

which I think this is not the right way to evaluate.

the main point of the evaluation is to find if the values `A B and C` are predicted correctly.

Comment: I replaced the word "accuracy" with "evaluation" in your question, because this word has a specific meaning: accuracy is an evaluation measure which is different from f-score for instance. Feel free to revert the changes if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to obtain a single f1-score when there are several classes, probably you are using **micro** or **macro** f1-score?

First don't use the micro F1-score, since it gives the same weight to every instance and therefore gives a lot of weight to the "X" class.

Macro F1-score should be closer to what you want to evaluate, since it gives every class equal weight. If you want you could even calculate the macro F1-score over only classes A,B,C (i.e. excluding X), but that seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: how can I do f1-score for ABC only?

Comment: f1 score is for a single class, for instance you calculate the f1-score for individual class A, B, C or X, it's a different score for each of them. Normally the macro f1-score is the mean of all the individual f1-scores across all classes, but instead you could do it across classes A,B,C only.